# JavaScript LINQ: can't get SingleOrDefault to return a single value

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, linq

I am using [this library](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) to get LINQ functionality in Javascript. However, I cannot get the SingleOrDefault() to work in my code. It returns multiple values.

Here is my (AngularJS) code:

```
customerService.getCustomer(customerId)
    .then(function (data) {
        $scope.customer = data.data;
        var primaryContact = Enumerable.From(data.data.contacts)
            .SingleOrDefault(function (x) { return x.isPrimaryContact });
        if (primaryContact) $scope.customer.address = primaryContact.address.addressLines;
        $scope.customer.customerType = 'DEFAULT';
    })
.catch(function (errorData) { alert("There has been an error retrieving the customer") });
```

The SingleOrDefault() returns multiple values even though I know for sure that there is only one contact that satisfies the condition.

Has anyone used this library and come across the same problem? Here is a sample of the XML being consumed:

```
  <contacts>
    <notification/>
    <address>
      <notification/>
      <addressId>400059994</addressId>
      <addressLines>My Address
      </addressLines>
      <country>9000</country>
      <county>East Sussex</county>
      <postcode>BN12 1PP</postcode>
      <town>Hove</town>
    </address>
    <contactId>400161871</contactId>
    <emailAddress>myemail@test.com</emailAddress>
    <isAccountsContact>false</isAccountsContact>
    <isAirlineListContact>false</isAirlineListContact>
    <isDefaultInvoicingContact>false</isDefaultInvoicingContact>
    <isDeleted>false</isDeleted>
    <isMarketingRegistered>true</isMarketingRegistered>
    <isPrimaryBrokerContact>false</isPrimaryBrokerContact>
    <isPrimaryContact>true</isPrimaryContact>
    <telephoneNumber>01273 123123</telephoneNumber>
    <website>www.fromthiscomesthat.co.uk</website>
  </contacts>
  <contacts>
    <notification/>
    <contactId>400161872</contactId>
    <customerContactType>15000</customerContactType>
    <forename>we</forename>
    <isAccountsContact>false</isAccountsContact>
    <isAirlineListContact>false</isAirlineListContact>
    <isDefaultInvoicingContact>false</isDefaultInvoicingContact>
    <isDeleted>false</isDeleted>
    <isMarketingRegistered>true</isMarketingRegistered>
    <isPrimaryBrokerContact>true</isPrimaryBrokerContact>
    <isPrimaryContact>false</isPrimaryContact>
    <surname>wew</surname>
    <title>A Test Contract</title>
  </contacts>
```

Comment: Can you show a short but complete example demonstrating the problem? (A simple array as source data should suffice...)

Comment: XML added above. As you can see only one of the contacts has isPrimaryContact set to true. I have just noticed that the SingleOrDefault() may not be returning any results at all, rather than more than one contact. There isn't very much documentation with this library...

Comment: I suggested a *short* but complete example - why use XML rather than a rather simpler data source such as an array? That way you could put the whole thing into one runnable snippet...

Comment: It's coming from an AngularJS service call.

Comment: I don't see why that would stop you from being able to put together a short but complete example which doesn't need AngularJS... I see nothing to suggest that the problem has anything to do with XML or AngularJS - and if you find that it *does* have something to do with that while you put together a short but complete example, you'll have learned something very important.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I changed one line to add a default value:

```
SingleOrDefault(null, function (x) { return x.isPrimaryContact })
```

I found some documentation [here](http://neue.cc/reference.htm), although I feel it could be a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use https://github.com/dibiancoj/
Great documentation and is very powerful. 
Found them from an infoq article last year:
http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/09/Linq-4-JavaScript